# Who wrote the Haggada?

Tags: history, passover-seder-hagada, historical-figures, authorship

Who wrote our haggada? Was is a tanna, amora or reishon?
I've heard different rumors from different people. Some say Rashi compiled it. Some say it was a tanna while others say it was an amora.

Comment: The Wikipedia article for ["Haggadah"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haggadah) has a section on authorship.

Comment: Hashem wrote it, just like He wrote all parts of the Toyruh

Comment: @bluejayke The only part of Torah dictated by Hashem is the Chumash. Everything else has human authors.

Comment: The Haggadah has sections, and different parts were added at different times. In particular, there were changes made after the destruction of the Second Temple when the  Pesach offering was no longer observed.

Comment: @bluejayke Hashem wrote "Rabban Gamliel omer"? In any event, Haggadah Sheleimah by Rav Menachem Mendel Kasher has a while writeup on this question.

Comment: @robev not crazier than His writing Devarim

Answer (score 2):

In the Sefer Hatoda'ah by  [Rabbi Eliyahu Kitov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliyahu_Kitov) he writes
[here](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=41319#p=105&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=)  and  [here](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=41319#p=106&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=) that from Yetzias Mitzrayim each person told the story to his family to the best of his ablity, except for the hallel that was said in mitzrayim was said and as time went on they added from the neviim and Dovid HaMelech until the Anshei Knesses HaGedolah came and wrote the main body of the Haggada and the brochos as we know it. As time went on the chachomim added and changed certain things in the Haggada such as they took out in the ma nishtana the question of eating the korban Pesach and added the question of haseibah and added the "ha lachma anya".

Comment: "except for the hallel that was said in mitzrayim was said" I wasn't able to comprehend this.